Use output redirection to change directory
I was working with BASH and used output redirection to save a directory path to a file. When I try to re-use the input stored in the file using input redirection it doesn't work.
I wrote 2 functions, one which redirects the output and the other which redirects input to the cd command.
#!/bin/bash



savepath () {


pwd > /home/user/Documents/save_path.txt

}

gotopath () {


cd < /home/user/Documents/save_path.txt

}

Save the shell script and made it executable. I then used source to enable myself to call my functions inside the shell.
After running the first savepath() and changing to any random directory, running the second function should send me back to the directory I ran savepath() from. It isn't doing that, instead it sends me to my home directory.

cd doesn’t use STDIN.

Try cd -- "$(< /home/user/Documents/save_path.txt)".

Are you aware that the instruction pwd just shows you the value of the environment variable $PWD? (Just do echo $PWD > /home/user/Documents/save_path.txt for saving the path)

If you need to save the path only for the duration of the script, why not save it in a variable instead of a file? saved_path=$PWD and cd -- "$saved_path" might do the trick. And then there are pushd and popd builtins to push and pop a directory.

You're passing the directory to cd as input rather than as a argument, but cd only takes arguments, not input. See "Command Line Arguments vs Input - What's the Difference?" and "What's the difference between STDIN and arguments passed to command?"

Thanks for the explanation. I'm a newbie so I was just stumbling along trying to make it work.

You guys are the best. Thank you very much for helping out. Had tried the approach suggested by Jens and it worked. I was stumped though over what might be causing the input redirection not to work.

Alternatively, look at xargs to convert STDIN to command line arguments.

Curiously enough I adjusted the gotopath function to look contain this: cat /home/user/Documents/save_path.txt | xargs -t cd and it gives me the following error regardless of whether I try Dominique's suggestion or I stick with the original : cd /home/x-ngin xargs: cd: No such file or directory. Do you guys have any idea what might be wrong, I've been raking my brain unsuccessfully ? I understand that we are probably past the point of diminishing returns but I thought this might help someone else.

a pipeline (cmd1 | cmd2) runs in a subshell context - changes are discarded when it finishes so cd is also undone. even if you get the xargs to run, the change won't stick

cd is a shell built-in. It would be pointless for it to be a standalone program; the directory change would immediately be lost when the program exited. xargs is telling you the truth - there is no such file or directory

Thanks for the explanation @jhnc. I think I need to go back and learn a bit more about how the shell itself works too. I definitely learnt a lot from this.

Try this:
#!/bin/bash

SAVEPATH=$HOME/Documents/save_path.txt

savepath () {
    pwd > $SAVEPATH
}

gotopath () {
    cd `cat $SAVEPATH`
}

The original implementation tried to pass the saved path via stdin. This is not the way that cd works: it needs the target directory as an argument. Using this approach the content of the file is substituted as an argument.


Thanks a lot for the explanation, datawookie. It definitely wasn't paying attention to the details of what I was doing - it was  the classical stick some code in and hope it runs.

Thanks datawookie, duly accepted. Still learning the ropes, didn't realise I had to do that.
